# How to store fabricjs objects in normalized cooridnates

Tags: fabricjs

I use fabricjs toJSON to store object coordinates into a .json file.
I then use loadFromJSON to reload the objects from the .json file.
The objects can be created on a bigger canvas and then restored into a smaller canvas.
Currently the objects are stored using absolute coordinates, so if restoring to a canvas with different size, the objects are renderred in different location on the canvas.
I'm looking for a way to store the objects in normalized coordinates (i.e. from 0,1) so that after de-normalization they will always render in the same place relative to the canvas.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scaling the object coordinates solved the problem for me (as suggested in [This link](https://groups.google.com/g/fabricjs/c/J-cWxrrstKQ?pli=1)).
The absolute coordinates are stored together with the canvas height and weight.
When loading from .json file, the ratio is computed and used to scale the coordinates, as well as other attributes such as the thickness of the free-draw pen.